# Where do Leaflet TimeDimension control images come from?

Tags: css, unicode

On http://apps.socib.es/Leaflet.TimeDimension/examples/example12.html the forward, backward and play buttons have an image inside. But where do these images come from? Where are they loaded?
In leaflet.timedimension.control.css they are defined to have \e072, \e073, etc. inside, but these are part of the "Private Use Area Unicode subset", so I presume, we'll have to define these somewhere. But where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to realize, that it is defined at the very beginning of leaflet.timedimension.control.css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src: url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
    src: url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg'); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the styles of this element in Developer Tools (F12), I see this:

```
.leaflet-bar-timecontrol .leaflet-control-timecontrol:before {
    font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
    display: block;
}
```

It's a webfont with icons: http://glyphicons.com/examples-of-use/